# With Kentor SAML authentication, is there a way to customize the User.Identity.Name?

Tags: .net, saml-2.0, kentor-authservices

We are currently implementing SAML authentication using Owin with Kentor in .NET.  We are reading the token correctly, and I receive all of the claims back.  However, when I parse the User.Identity object that Owin returns to me, there isn't a name on it (that I would have if I was using Azure Active Directory, etc.).  Does anyone know of a way to use some of the returning claims from the token to set the User.Identity.Name?  In this case, the claims in question are EmpFirstName and EmpLastName.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a third option to the two (better) answers that Anders has provided:

When I needed to do this I located the claim I wanted to be the username and created a new claim with:

```
 subject.AddClaim(new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name",claim.Value));
```

Identity will then recognise it.

Comment: I'll play with that one and see what turns up.  Thank you.

Comment: No problem. There may be better places to put it, but I went for in the ProcessAuthenticationStatement as I wasnt sure at what stage the claims get processed into an identity and wanted to make sure i got in beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this.

1. Implement a `ClaimsAuthenticationManager` (see the Kentor AuthServices docs in the GitHub repo) that is a callback mechanism during the claims creation. You can also use the `AcsCommandResultCreated` notification if you find that easier to use. In there, add a Name claim that you want (e.g. by combining the existing first and last name claims).
2. If you want the `Identity.Name` to point to an existing claim, change the `NameClaimType` property of the Identity.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.  A question - as we are doing this through code as opposed to configuration, it appears that we would be using the following:
    spOptions.SystemIdentityModelIdentityConfiguration.ClaimsAuthenticationManager.LoadCustomConfiguration() where we would need to pass in an XML to make it understand.  What would be an example of the XML that we would need to pass to concatenate EmpFirstName and EmpLastName from existing claims into the Identity.Name property?